# Axiom of Pairing

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Axiom of Pairing states that if $a,b$ are sets, $\exists$ a set $A$ such that $A=\{{a,b\}}$.But why we can't just write the set $A=\{a,b\}$ explicitly so we don't need that axiom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formally speaking, the fact that you can write $\{a,b\}$ doesn't mean that it exists in your model.

You can also write $\frac12$ quite explicitly, and yet it doesn't exist in $\Bbb Z$.

And similarly you can write $-1,\sqrt2$ and $\sqrt{-1}$ which don't exist in $\Bbb{N,Q,R}$ respectively.

Comment: Does that mean that the originally existing set is only $\phi$

Comment: No. There is no "originally existing set". If you have a model, then it everything in that model already exists. What can you prove that exists is a whole other thing. If you don't assume the axiom of infinity, can you prove that $\omega$ exists? No, you can't, but it might exist in a given model regardless. Existence is really a semantic "property", so when you talk about things which exist you invariably talk about a model. So once a model is taken, everything inside of it exists. The question is whether or not you can prove that a given set exists (so it would exist in all models).

Comment: Sorry I couldn't get your idea, so e.x. can I treat a wolf a set?

Comment: No, you can't. Because sets are mathematical objects and wolves are not. Although strictly speaking, you can treat whatever you want however you want, it's up to other people decide if their time is worth spending listening to a madman, though. The point is that there are two parts, syntax where logic and axioms and proving things live; and semantics where actual objects "exist" (in the mathematical sense), where statements are true or false and not just provable. So given a model of set theory, in order to ensure that certain things exist we want to prove their existence from the axioms [...]

Comment: So we need to have suitable axioms. But existence, per se, is a statement about models. So even if I gave you a model of set theory, and you know that $\{a,b\}$ exists in that model. You still want to be able and ensure that if I gave you another model, such set would exist there (given that $a,b$ are in the other model too). And this is what the axioms give you, the ability to prove that the set $\{a,b\}$ exists. And if you can prove something, then it is true in all the models of the theory.

Comment: Does that mean(not rigorous), if we already have rational number, and the axiom tells us that the limit of rational number exists,then we get irrational number?

Comment: No. And now I'm worried that I completely confused you.

Comment: Another question: Without the Axiom of Specification,we can't assume that a subset of a set exists,right?

Comment: Not in general, no. Unless we have some other means to prove that (e.g. Axiom of Replacement).

Answer (score 0):

In informal proofs of the kind you see in most mathematics textbooks, the author can get away with simply writing $A=\{a,b\}$ as you suggest without having to cite any particular axiom to justify it.

In formal proofs on, say, some foundational issue, the author would have to explicitly cite the Pairing Axiom to justify $A=\{a,b\}$, the proof being a test of the system of axioms used as much as anything else.